# How to get the url from uri, uri given as string

Tags: 8, uri

I have a string

```
$directory = "/home/ .../sites/default/files..."
```

I tried to get the absolute url with:

```
$MYURL = Url::fromUri("base://".$directory);
```

That leads to an exception!

Can anybody explain hot to retrieve the url from a string?

Comment: file_create_url($path)

Answer (score 5):

Thx for your comments,

but I found the answer by investigating the core modules:

```
preg_match('/sites(.*)/',$directory,$matches);
$url_new = $matches[1];
$MYURL = Url::fromUri('base:/sites'.$url_new, array('absolute' => TRUE))->toString();
```

Hope this helps some other guys too!

Comment: a) \Drupal::service('site.path') and b) if we're talking files here then Url::fromUri('public://somefile/somewhere/is.jpg')->toString().

Comment: This should work for any uri string (public:, base:, internal:, or absolute).  $urlObj = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri($uriString); $urlObj->toString();

Answer (score 4):

Based on that string alone you'll never get a url. Do you mean how do you get the url of the current site?

In Drupal you don't need to. As Ivan recommended in his comment, you just need

This is the way to do it if the file was uploaded in Drupal and you have the uri.

`file_create_url($path)`
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/8

If you don't have the URI (for example you need to link to a file in your theme, then use:

```
drupal_get_path('theme', 'your_theme');
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_path/8

Then combine that with a link *relative to the theme* instead of relative to the server root like your current $directory is:

```
$directory = "files/myfile.png";
```

Then jam them together:

```
$my_url = drupal_get_path('theme', 'your_theme')."/".$directory;
```

If you do need the full site URL for some reason, you should be able to use `global $base_url;`
(a global variable in Drupal) or check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/14500505/430191